# migration rollback reverts the previous schema but previous data is lost

Tags: laravel, migration, database-migration, laravel-migrations

I have a users table having the following schema:

**Users**
 - id
 - name
 - username
 - password

This table contains 10 records and i update the schema using migration. 
Then I drop the column **name** and add two columns **firstName** and **lastName** the updated users table schema is given below:

**Updated Users Table**
 - id
 - firstName
 - lastName
 - username
 - password

Then I use migration rollback to bring back my previous schema

**Users**
 - id
 - name
 - username
 - password

but now my data for the **name** column is lost? Should not migration bring me back at the previous state (by restoring both the previous schema and the data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. Migrations **only** take care of the database structure. It has nothing to do with your data. In fact, by default when you roll a previous migration back, the rollback performs a *table drop*, which means that all data within that table is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think **migration can bring back (restore) our data** by a little more effort. we can write a routine in the **up()** section which can take the backup and a corresponding routine in the **down()** section which can restore the previous schema as well the backed up data.